# Arrange the following functions in a list so that each function is the Big-O of the next function.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, education

Arrange in increasing order of complexity 
the list is: $\sqrt{n}, 1000\log(n), n \log(n), 2n!, 2^n, \frac{n^2}{1000}$

My answer is:

$$\sqrt{n}, 1000\log(n), n \log n, 2^n, 2n!,\frac{n^2}{1000}$$

Is this the right order in your opinion?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any method you had for arranging these in this order? Did you guess, use intuition, graph the functions, or prove that any of these were the Big-O of any of the others or did you use some other method for ordering these the way you have ordered them?

Comment: @benguin I kind of used intuition at first but then tried to find the big-O notation for them if the variables were replaced with numbers but then I got a litte lost :D

Comment: Simply plugging in random numbers does not suffice to calculate Big-O. Big-O is more so about long term growth, so it is possible to get an intuition if you plug in really large numbers and/or plot the functions, but you can not 100% depend on this method since there is always the question about whether or not you went out far enough. One thing to keep in mind is that any constant multiples have no effect on the Big-O, thus $1000\log(n)$ is $\mathcal{O}\log(n)$ and vice versa.

Comment: I'll tell you that the middle four functions in your answer are correctly ordered relative to each other, but you need to move the $\sqrt{n}$ and the $n^2/1000$ somewhere else. Try to think a little more in terms of rate of growth, for example, we know that eventually, if $x$ is big enough, then $x^3 > x^2$.

Comment: okay, because plugging in numbers def. made it more confusing to me. Okay here is my attempt again:   n2/1000,1000log(n),nlogn,2n,2n!, √,n
 Division holds back the exponential growth right? @benguin

Comment: In regards to exponential growth, the $1000$'s in both $n^2/1000$ and $1000\log(n)$ have no bearing since it is just a constant multiple and constant multiples of a function don't change its complexity. Thus, you can treat the $n^2/1000$ as you would $n^2$ and treat the $1000\log(n)$ as you would $\log(n)$. Your ordering is still incorrect; the middle four are correct (relative to each other) but you need to stick the $\sqrt{n}$ and $n^2/1000$ somewhere inbetween.

Comment: 1000log(n),nlogn,‾√n, ,2n, n^2/1000,2n!, Hopefully this is the right order? @benguin Sorry if I still don't get it

Comment: Close! You want to swap the $n\log(n)$ and the $\sqrt{n}$. Notice that for $n$ large enough $\sqrt{n} < n < n \cdot \log(n)$.

Comment: oh yeah I see it now! Thank you so much! @benguin I've been trying to understand the Big-O notation for a while now :D thanks again!

Comment: No problem :) I've added an answer that more thoroughly explains the ordering and some of the things discussed in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

First, we know that a constant multiple of a function doesn't change the complexity of the functions, so our problem reduces to ordering the following functions:

$$\sqrt{n},\log(n), n \log(n), n!, 2^n, n^2.$$

It is helpful to remember a general hierarchy of functions, ordered by their growth complexity:

$$1 \to \log(n) \to n^c \to n^c\log(n) \to n^{c+\varepsilon}\to d^n \to n! \to n^n$$

where $c, \varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$ and $d \in (1,\infty)$.

When comparing two different powers of $n$, say $n^c$ and $n^d$ where $c,d\in (0,\infty)$, then we have:
$$n^c \text{ is } \mathcal{O}(n^d) \iff c\leq d.$$

Similarly, for $c,d\in (1,\infty)$,
$$c^n \text{ is } \mathcal{O}(d^n) \iff c\leq d.$$

This information is enough to uniquely order the functions as:
$$1000\log(n), \sqrt{n},n\log(n),\frac{n^2}{1000}, 2^n, 2n!$$